# clicking text in an html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How do I program the canvas to set go = true; in regular js when you click on the word "play" on the canvas? if go = true, it starts the game. this code prints play onto the canvas. . this is my js code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 336;


    var go = false;

    var reset = function() {
        //reset function
    };

    var main = function () {
    //main function
    };

    var menu = function () {

        ctx.clearRect (0 , 0 , canvas.width , canvas.height);

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 250, 250)";
        ctx.font = "24px Helvetica";
        ctx.textAlign = "left";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.fillText("play", 32, 32);
    }

    if (go == true) {
        reset();
        var then = Date.now();
        setInterval(main, 1);
    }
    else {
        menu();
    }
```

Comment: set what? where? what needs to be clicked?

Comment: the var "go" has to be equal to true. the code above is what needs to be clicked. I didn't want to put my entire project there because its like 200 lines

Comment: @Chase You just need to clarify the issue and what you want to accomplish. The way your statements read, you want to set a variable when the user clicks on a line of code. I assume you meant the line of text that the code renders, but it's not entirely clear currently. And, no, you don't need to include the whole project here, but a [trimmed-down and functional example](http://jsfiddle.net/) would help.

Comment: That setInterval will, probably "kill" your code as it try to update the loop every 1 ms. Use at worst *setTimeout* inside your main(), better, use requestAnimationFrame. Where do you draw the Play button?

Comment: its a game, so its rendering as many frames as it possibly can. it draws the play button at the top left, if thats what you mean.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I need glasses... never mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you can adjust is these parts as using a `setInterval` with 1 ms will do not good:

```
var main = function () {
    //main function

   if (go === true) setTimeout(main, 16);
   //use requestAnimationFrame(main) instead, 
};
```

To check for click on the button you can do something like this:

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/n8Hsd/

Define a rectangle where text would be:

```
rect = {
    x: 32,
    y: 32,
    w: 70,
    h: 30
};
//this is not proper way to calculate text boundary,
//but for demo's sake.
ctx.fillText("play", rect.x, rect.y + 16);
```

Then listen to canvas' click event and check if clicked position is inside that rectangle:

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', checkStart, false);

function checkStart(e) {
    var p = getMousePos(e);

    if (p.x >= rect.x && p.x <= rect.x + rect.w &&
        p.y >= rect.y && p.y <= rect.y + rect.h) {

        go = !go;
        if (go === true) {
            main();
        } else {
            menu();
        }
    }
}
```

The mouse position can be calculated like this:

```
function getMousePos(e) {
    var r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: e.clientX - r.left,
        y: e.clientY - r.top
    };
}
```

Comment: for some reason my text isn't showing up now. the entire project is at https://github.com/INOVA-Technology/GCGames if you want to check it out.

Comment: o, wait... I think i see my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check whether the mouse in inside the text's bounding box when the canvas is clicked. If the mouse's position is inside the text's bounding box when clicking, then the text is being clicked and you should set `go` to `true`.

Something like this will help.

```
var bbox = {x:10,y:10, w:100, h:100};
if(mouseX >= bbox.x && mouseY >= bbox.y && mouseX <= bbox.x + bbox.w && mouseY <= bbox.y + bbox.h){
    go = true;
}
```

Comment: how would I define mouseX and mouseY?

Comment: @Chase You should put this inside the canvas' click event handler. The mouse position can be defined as `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY`.

Comment: @Chase `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY` is not supported in all browsers so something like `jQuery` may come in handy.